# Google AdSense ad serving has been disabled. So How to handle it?

Tags: seo, google-adsense, api

I have a site which pulls photos from Instagram API. Recently I got a shocking message from Google that "Google AdSense ad serving has been disabled" for the "ADULT/PORNOGRAPHY" reason.

I believe that Instagram won't allow users to upload "ADULT/PORNOGRAPHY" content. So my website also won't contain such kind of photos(ADULT/PORNOGRAPHY).

Unfortunately, a user from instagram (http://instagram.com/shoutoutsforeveryoneallthetime - Now removed from instagram :) ) uploaded ADULT/PORNOGRAPHY photos and so, Adsense caught my website page for the same user and so it has been stopped from displaying ads from my website.

Sorry for such a long story.

Please suggest to me how to deal with this scenario. If I start another site same like this, what will happen to me? And I just want to know some other sites which also display photos from Instagram, which still have active Adsense ads.

More than that, most local NEWS websites may contain words like fu.., bo.., porn...etc., But still they display ads from Google. Google Won't block their Ads.

Please explain.

Comment: Congrats!! How long did they take to reinstate?

Comment: with 48 hrs....

Answer (score 1):

I think that there wont be any more explanations than [Google adsense policies](http://support.google.com/adsense/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=48182)

> Sites with Google ads may not include or link to: 
>   Pornography, adult
>   or mature content ...

So if Google doesn't see it, you wont be fired, a bad advise : "not seen, not taken".
It's the only reason I see why other websites, that displays some bad contents, are not fired today. But tomorrow...

BTW, before stoping adsense diffusion on a website, Google usualy warn the webmaster to modify his page. And if the webmaster doesn't do it, Google stop the diffusion on the page, or on the website, or could close the account.

On how to prevent "porn" picture's display on your website, you may :

- Control by yourself what is posted and remove it
- Add a flag feature to be informed by users/visitors of "bad" contents

To do it automatically, you'll need some picture analysis system, with a very expensive cost !

Comment: I can't believe in your concept "Not seen, not taken". Because, other site(similar to my website) which has 1,650,000 indexed pages in Google. And Still it has active Google Adsense. But for my website, it is just 183,000 indexed pages only. I think, Google also measuring page rank or using some other measurement before a site block from Google Adsense.

Comment: I can ensure you, by experience, that with or without PR (deprecated), if some pages doesn't follow the policies, the webmaster get some warns. If he doesn't modify the page(s) adsense can be blocked on this page(s). With several warns, the adsense can be block on the entire website or the account closed. But it happens only when there is a verification on your account, it's why I wrote "not seen, not taken", wich is a bad avise, as I wrote too.

Answer (score 1):

As you know Google love original content and its your job to check if the content is displayed from outer than your Site, or some other link, does this follow the Google's policy, if not you have to remove those auto generated content from the Site immediately.

you yourself think, why you should suffer for someone else's mistake? so i would rather recommend you to start over with your own content and must be independent (for best).

Additionally you can also send a Re-initiation request to Google Adsense team mentioning complete reason and how you are now able to follow their guidelines.
hope Google may allow the ads again!
All the best

Answer (score 1):

I presume you have submitted an appeal? https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/request.py?contact_type=policy_disabled_appeal

If you have not had any luck through that channel, then I think you might be stuck.

Wish I had better news, but I have not had good experiences with adsense.

A client of mine was banned for very vague reasons and didn't get any response from appeals; even leveraging contacts of contacts inside google could not get them unblocked and one google insider even claimed they weren't blocked even though the adsense does not work at all - it gets a 403 forbidden.

My advice would be to find alternative sources of income because google's decisions are often final. I would even go as far to advise any against using it as their primary income source for any new projects.

But I hope I am wrong, if you get better outcome please post it on here as it would be very useful :)

Comment: Thanks.Yesterday i submitted an appeal to Google and i am waiting for that... Based on the Suggestion(other blogs), i have tried the "Chitika" ads, It is okay if your website has good in US traffic.

But It is not the best alternative to the Google Adsense, i earned from Chitika (30:1), which means if i get $30 / per day from Adsense, then i got $1 / per day from Chitika or may be less.

Comment: you have my sympathy; there are hundreds of ad networks out there, and I don't see any way around trying them one by one until you find one that earns well in your particular circumstances

Comment: Just now, i got email from Google and they re-enabled ad serving to my site.

Answer (score 0):

My personal suggestion: before you quit Google Adsense, you can apply for a review of your account. It can help to restore your account. You have to fill in all the right information. https://support.google.com/adsense/bin/request.py?contact_type=policy_disabled_appeal